# Google Plus Share using Address Book Framework rejected in Apple Store

Tags: ios, sdk, app-store, google-plus

I got this error "App uses the Address Book API, which allows access to the users Address Book database. This feature is not fully implemented within the app.". 
If the AddressBook framework is removed then the app wont build causing errors in Google Plus SDK classes. How do I get it approved or fix this issue?

Comment: i feel like there is no way one can hep you without more information. What sdk's libraries you are using, etc.

Comment: The Google Plus SDK version we are using is 1.5.0